# How to cache fetched image by FadeInImage.assetNetwork

Tags: flutter

I'm using `FadeInImage.assetNetwork` to fetch an image from the server, the problem is it fetches and animates every time it's loading the image.

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
            placeholder: Assets.emptyPlaceholder,
            image: order.icon,
            width: 36,
            height: 36,
          )
```

Is there any solution to cache the fetched image and show it as a placeholder, then if the original image from the server has been changed, change the placeholder too.

Comment: what did you end up doing here? i'm having the same issue. just looks weird to have an image fade-in a 2nd time when it's already been loaded/displayed once (it seems to fade-in again on any rebuild).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use

```
FadeInImage(
 image: CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: 'https://backend.example.com/image.png',
  placeholder: Assets.emptyPlaceholder,
            image: order.icon,
            width: 36,
            height: 36,
),
)
```

Comment: I got "The argument type 'CachedNetworkImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'." with this. How can I use FadeInImage with CachedNetworkImage ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you give what code you are using? Are you trying to execute the same code above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FadeInImage(
  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(order.icon),
  placeholder: AssetImage(Assets.emptyPlaceholder),
  width: 36,
  height: 36,
)
```